# Deactivate hyphenation only in certain paragraphs

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a Microsoft Word document where *hyphenation* is enabled.

Now, there are paragraphs/headings, where I want to turn off hyphenation. 
Two solutions came to my mind:

1. Deactivate the hyphenation while the cursor is in the paragraph. But this disables the hyphenation for the whole document.
2. Manually changing the hyphenation pattern. But this again changes the hyphenation throughout the whole text.

So my question is: Is there a way to disable hyphenation for a selected part of text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible!

Turn off hyphenation for selected paragraphs by following these steps:

1. Make sure that the cursor is somewhere in the paragraph, where the hyphenation should be disabled.
2. Choose **Paragraph** from the format menu/right click menu.
3. Select the tab **Line and Page Breaks**.
4. Check the **Don't Hyphenate** checkbox.
5. Click OK, and you are done!

As suggested by *martineau* it is also possible the specify this in a custom style.

Comment: It should be possible to create a custom style based on the Normal style + no hyphenation and give it a name. That way, the OP could explicitly easily assign that style to just specific paragraphs.